# Failing to connect to remote mongodb server

Tags: linux, mongodb, vagrant, admin

I am trying to create a remote mongodb server to work with on my java project.

I am using vagrant + ansible to create the environment, but fr soem reson i cannot get a connection.

I always get connection refused through the network. the same code on localhost works perfectly.

I am using vagrant box: `chef/centos-6.5`

and my ansible tasks are as follows:

> ```
> - name: Download EPEL Repo
>   get_url: url=http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel- release-6-8.noarch.rpm dest=/tmp/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
> - name: Install EPEL Repo
>   command: rpm -ivh /tmp/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm creates=/etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo
> - name: Install libselinux-python
>   yum: name=libselinux-python
> - name: Create the repository for 10Gen  
>   copy: src=10gen.repo.j2 dest=/etc/yum.repos.d/10gen.repo
> - name: Create the EPEL Repository.
>   copy: src=epel.repo.j2 dest=/etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo
> - name: Create the GPG key for EPEL
>   copy: src=RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-6 dest=/etc/pki/rpm-gpg
> - name: Create the mongod user
>   user: name=mongod comment="MongoD"
> - name: Create the data directory for the namenode metadata
>   file: path={{ mongodb_datadir_prefix }} owner=mongod group=mongod state=directory
> - name: Install the mongodb package
>   yum: name={{ item }} state=installed
>   with_items:
>    - libselinux-python
>    - mongo-10gen
>    - mongo-10gen-server
>    - bc
>    - python-pip
> - name: Install the latest pymongo package
>   pip: name=pymongo state=latest use_mirrors=no
> ```

i have added the iptables exceptions:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 27017 -j ACCEPT
```

which is active:

> ```
> [root@localhost ~]# iptables -L -v
> Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 209 packets, 13148 bytes)
>  pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
>  1070 68777 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:27017
> ```

my java code defining `MongoDbFactory`

> ```
> public @Bean
> MongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory() throws Exception {
>     MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient("<ip-of-machine>", 27017);
>     return new SimpleMongoDbFactory(mongo, "test");
> }
> ```

But i always get the following exception when trying to connect to it.

```
com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 10000 ms while waiting for a server that matches AnyServerSelector{}. Client view of cluster state is {type=Unknown, servers=[{address=192.168.1.11:27017, type=Unknown, state=Connecting, exception={com.mongodb.MongoException$Network: Exception opening the socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused}}]
```

If i run mongodb from localhost and change the ip accordingly, everything works fine.

Thanks

Comment: Can you telnet to the target address and port? `telnet <ip-of-machine> 27017`

Comment: no, that doesnt work: MacBook-Pro:~ me$ telnet 192.168.1.11:27017
192.168.1.11:27017: nodename nor servname provided, or not known.          Ping works though

Comment: That's not right, don't use a colon between host and port when using telnet. `telnet 192.168.1.11 27017`

Comment: Sorry, but still doesnt work on connection refused. MacBook-Pro:~ me$ telnet 192.168.1.11 27017
Trying 192.168.1.11...
telnet: connect to address 192.168.1.11: Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host

Comment: Yep, if you can't connect maybe you're trying to hit the wrong host. Your iptables rules look ok at first glance. Can you ping that host?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69036/discussion-between-gleeb-and-chris-fei).

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Firstly, To ensure its not a firewall issue, stop IPTABLES on both servers (don't forget to re-enable afterwards).

On the machine that you are trying to connect to, ssh directly to it and ensure MongoDB is running, Connect locally and check that you can access a DB.

MongoDb isn't configured to accept connections from remote hosts by default, could you ensure you have these lines in your `/etc/mongodb.conf` file:

```
bind_ip = 0.0.0.0
port = 27017
```

Make sure you restart MongoDB after making any changes. Try this and comment if your still having issues and I'll update the answer with more suggestions.

**EDIT:** As of version 2.6 the config file format has changed to YAML, details [here](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/), the file should be located at `/etc/mongod.conf`.

```
net:
   bindIp: 0.0.0.0
   port: 27017
```

Comment: Holy mother of god it was the bind_ip. Thank you so much.!

Comment: nice, Glad to of helped. Please ensure you re-enable iptables if you disabled it :)

Comment: Make sure that your MongoClient is connecting on the correct port `27017`
URL pattern being like `mongodb://localhost:27017/my_database_name`


`Restart the service` on Ubuntu `service mongodb restart`

Comment: What is the reason of having 2 different configuraiton files for binding port ? I have both on my version deployed on Ubuntu

Comment: from v2.6 the config file type changed to YAML, you should only really have one

Comment: I tried this solution, but It does not work for me. Ping command return ok, but remote connection fails.

Comment: @Scriptable - Instead of 0.0.0.0   Can't we specify specific server's IP address? 0.0.0.0 could be a security issue?

Comment: @SachinVairagi if you like yeah, read the docs and try it out :)

Comment: @Scriptable - Thanks for your response, BTW I tried it but it didn't work :(

Comment: @SachinVairagi Check out these docs, they should help explain how to do it: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/security-mongodb-configuration/