# No server chosen by WritableServerSelector from cluster

Tags: java, mongodb

As a newbie to MongoDB I'm trying to insert a simple document into my freshly installed mongoDB (v3.2.4). MongoDB Driver 3.2.2 is used.
Here my minimized code:

```
public <classname>()
{
    public static final String COLLECTION_NAME = "logs";
    MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("<server-adress>");
    MongoDatabase db = mongoClient.getDatabase("test");

    Document  data = new Document ();
    data.append(<whatever>);
    //...inserting more into document...
    db.getCollection(COLLECTION_NAME).insertOne(data); //collection should be created new

    mongoClient.close();
}
```

The programm is executing, but I'm getting the following errors (and informations) during execution:

```
Mär 16, 2016 3:50:06 PM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFORMATION: Cluster created with settings {hosts=[<server-adress>:27017], mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', maxWaitQueueSize=500}
Mär 16, 2016 3:50:06 PM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFORMATION: No server chosen by WritableServerSelector from cluster description ClusterDescription{type=UNKNOWN, connectionMode=SINGLE, all=[ServerDescription{address=<server-adress>:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING}]}. Waiting for 30000 ms before timing out
Mär 16, 2016 3:50:07 PM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFORMATION: Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server <server-adress>:27017
com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
    at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:63)
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:114)
    at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:128)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    (...) 
    at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStreamHelper.initialize(SocketStreamHelper.java:50)
    at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:58)
    ... 3 more

Error: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for a server that matches WritableServerSelector. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=<server-adress>:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect}}]
```

The document is also not inserted.

When I'm commenting the line with the insertOne()-command, it disappears. So I assume it isnt' a problem with the connection, is that right?

I've some ideas:

- Does it has something to do with asynchronity? I'd be suprized, I said nowhere that I don't want to execute it synchronous.
- Are any permissions missing  (because of this `WritableServerSelector`-Thing)?
- Does it has to do with the "test"-database?
- Are there problems with the stand-alone-mode of MongoDB? (I don't want to use replicasets.)

But for all these ideas I couldn't find real proofs...

(Please improve the question-title, I had no better idea...)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Solved it on my own.

I also should have mentioned, that I'm trying to connect from another machine to the MongoDB-instance. That is not allowed with the MongoDB-presets.

So I had to change in the /etc/mongod.conf File the value behind `bindIp` from 127.0.0.1 to 0.0.0.0.

[[Source]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28003525/2831409)

Comment: Good answer, it saved my time :) I can add here, that another option to specify the bindIp is command line arguments, like that: 
`mongod --bind_ip=0.0.0.0`
 Thanks!