# Can't start mongoDB as a service

Tags: mongodb, replicaset

I'd like to run mongoDB as a service. The instance shall be configured as a single-node replicaset to be able to connect a elasticSearch instance to it with a [the connector](https://github.com/mongodb-labs/mongo-connector).

So I extended the mongod.conf:

```
...
replication:
  replSetName: "singleNodeRepl"
...
```

I tried different ways to start now the mongod, but nothing works.

When I try to start the service by `$ service mongod start`, following error is thrown:

```
start: Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.106" (uid=1225 pid=26018 comm="start mongod ") interface="com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6.Job" member="Start" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="com.ubuntu.Upstart" (uid=0 pid=1 comm="/sbin/init")
```

When I execute this command as `sudo` (whats not best-practise, right?), its "running" and following message is shown:

```
mongod start/running, process 26034
```

But process 26034 doesn't exist and  `ps aux | grep mongo` also shows nothing?!

Next try: Run it as a normal application

```
mongod --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb/ --replSet SingleNodeRepl
```

Here following exception is shown:

```
2016-04-08T14:31:35.192+0200 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 98 Unable to create/open lock file: /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock errno:13 Permission denied Is a mongod instance already running?, terminating
2016-04-08T14:31:35.192+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] dbexit:  rc: 100
```

Everything is fine when I run `~$ sudo mongod --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb/ --replSet SingleNodeRepl`, but thats not my target: Its not running as a service and its running as root.

The mongod-logfile often keeps untouched. But the last lines are curious:

```
2016-04-08T14:24:56.242+0200 E NETWORK  [initandlisten] Failed to unlink socket file /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock errno:1 Operation not permitted
2016-04-08T14:24:56.242+0200 I -        [initandlisten] Fatal Assertion 28578
2016-04-08T14:24:56.242+0200 I -        [initandlisten]
***aborting after fassert() failure
```

A mongodb-27017.sock existed, but deleting (what was suggested anywhere) didn't help.

Based on the erros above if [tried](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12232668/2831409) serveral [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14473446/2831409), but nothing helps.

I think it's a very simple mistake...but which one?

[edit:]
I discovered, that I perhaps should have specified the config-location. So the (working but bad) command looks like:

```
$ sudo mongod --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb/ --replSet SingleNodeRepl --config /etc/mongod.conf
```

This brings following error:

```
warning: bind_ip of 0.0.0.0 is unnecessary; listens on all ips by default
```

Thats an old thing, which was the solution for [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36041153/2831409) and suddenly doesn't work anymore!?

Comment: In the logs, I noticed a lock file couldn't be created or opened.  Could it be a user permission issue?  What's the permissions for the ``/var/lib/mongodb/``?

Comment: `rwxr-xr-x 4 mongodb       mongodb       4096 Apr  8 14:31 mongodb`

Comment: Did you try deleting both the .sock and .lock file?

Comment: I extended my question.

Comment: Might just be a typo but I noticed you have  "singleNodeRepl" in your conf file and "SingleNodeRepl" on the command line in your edit.  Perhaps try starting again with just the config param. So `mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf`

Comment: Ha, thats not just a typo in my question! Well observed, great, thanks!
But that doesn't solve my service-problem :/

Answer (score 0):

I've had issues stopping and starting mongod as a service. Turns out there was an issue with the upsart script. 
I found this [discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/mongodb-user/1-tRRGCTvoA/9ILjGMPVO74J) which seemed to fix it.

The suggested solution was pretty much: (copy pasting now)

`vim /etc/init.d/mongod`

look for stop() function (and start() function for good measure) and remove quotes around $PIDFILE in the following line.

`killproc -p $PIDFILE -d 300 /usr/bin/mongod`

Comment: interesting. mongod is missing in /etc/init.d/ on my machine?!
But I've done everything mentioned here (https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu) during installation?!
Of course! It has something to do with the switch from init.d to SysV on ubuntu! Investigation in process...

Comment: Could be this problem here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10733201/mongodb-is-not-starting-in-ubuntu

Comment: That would be strange if you followed the ubuntu instructions and didn't get a mongod file. Perhaps create one as suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock
mongod --repair
sudo service mongodb start
```

Let me know if this doesn't work!

Comment: I did this already in a similar way as mentioned in the question.
When I do this (with correct dbpath), I get this error:
`exception in initAndListen: 98 Unable to create/open lock file: /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock errno:13 Permission denied Is a mongod instance already running?, terminating` But the mongod.lock doesn't exist (anymore). Crazy.