# connection refused connecting to remote mongodb server

Tags: linux, mongodb, debian

So we've accumulated enough applications in our network that use MongoDB to justify building a dedicated server specifically for MongoDB. Unfortunately, I'm pretty new to mongodb (coming from SQL/MySQL derivatives). I have followed several guides on installing and configuring mongodb for my environment. None are perfect, but I think I'm close... I've have managed to get to a point that I can connect to the db server from the local server using the following command:

```
mongo -u user 127.0.0.1/admin
```

However, I'm NOT able to connect to the server using this from either the local OR a remote computer using it's network address, IE:

```
mongo -u user 192.168.24.102/admin
```

I've tried both with authentication enabled and disabled, and I've tried setting the bindIP to 192.168.24.102 and 0.0.0.0 with no love. Thinking it was a Firewall issue, I disabled the firewall entirely... same. no love...

so what's the secret sauce? how do I connect to a MongoDB server remotely?

Some notes to know: This server is on a local network only. There will be some NAT shenanigans at some point directing public traffic to it from remote application servers, but only specific ports (we will NOT be using 27017 when that happens) and it will sit behind a pretty robust firewall appliance, so I'm not worried about securing the server as I about securing MongoDB itself.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28003525/551744

Answer (score 2):

This answer assume a setup where a Linux server is completely remote and has MongoDB already installed.

**Steps:**

**1. Connect to your remote server over SSH.**

```sh
ssh <userName>@<server-IP-address>
```

**2. Start Mongo shell and add users to MongoDB.**

Add the admin;

```js
use admin
db.createUser(
  {
    user: "AdminSammy",
    pwd: "AdminSammy'sSecurePassword",
    roles: [ 
             {"userAdminAnyDatabase",
              "dbAdminAnyDatabase",
              "readWriteAnyDatabase"}
           ]
  }
)
```

Then add general user/users. Users are added to specific databases.

```js
use some_db

db.createUser({
    user: 'userName',
    pwd: 'secretPassword',
    roles: [{ role: 'readWrite', db:'some_db'}]
})
```

**3. Edit your MongoDB config file, `mongod.conf`, that is found in `etc` directory.**

```sh
sudo vim /etc/mongod.conf
```

Scroll down to the `#security:` section and add the following line. Make sure to un-comment the `security:` line.

```yaml
security:
  authorization: 'enabled'
```

After authorization has been enabled only those authenticated with password will access the database. In this case these are the ones added in `step 2` above.

**Note:** Visual Studio code can also be used over SSH to edit the `mongo.conf` file.

**4. Add remote server's IP address to mongod.conf file.**

Look for the `net` line and add the IP address of the server that is hosting this MongoDB installation, example `178.45.55.88`

```yaml
# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1, 178.45.55.88
```

**5. Open port 27017 on your server instance**.

This allows access to your MongoDB server from anywhere in the world to anyone who knows your remote server IP address. This is one reason to have authenticated users. More robust ways of handling security are really important! Consult [MongoDB manual](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/) for that.

Check firewall status using `ufw`.

```sh
sudo ufw status
```

If its not active, activate it.

```sh
sudo ufw enable
```

Then,

```sh
sudo ufw allow 27017
```

> **Important:** You also need to allow port 22 for your SSH communication with your remote server. Otherwise you will be locked out from your remote server. Assumption here is that SSH uses port 22 for communication, the default.

```sh
sudo ufw allow 22
```

**6. Restart Mongo daemon (mongod)**

```sh
sudo systemctl restart mongod
```

**7. Connect to remote Mongo server using Mongo shell**

You can now connect to the remote MongoDB server using the following command.

```sh
mongo -u <user-name> -p <user-password> <remote-server-IP-address>:<mongo-server-port>
```

You can also connect to the remote MongoDB server with authentication:

```sh
mongo -u <user-name> -p <user-password> <remote-server-IP-address>:<mongo-server-port> --authenticationDatabase <auth-db-name>
```

You can also connect to a specific remote MongoDB database with authentication:

```sh
mongo -u <user-name> -p <user-password> <remote-server-IP-address>:<mongo-server-port>/<db-name> --authenticationDatabase <auth-db-name>
```

At this moment you can read and write within the `some_db` database from your local computer without `ssh`.

> **Important:** Put into consideration the standard security measures for any database. Local security practices should guide what to do at any of the above steps.