# Connection refused for remote access of mongodb server

Tags: linux, mongodb, ubuntu

I have set up a mongo server on my local desktop machine (running Ubuntu 20.04), and I can connect to it without any issue on that machine. However, when I try to connect from my laptop, it shows this error:

```
connecting to: mongodb://<my ip address>:27017/admin?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Error: couldn't connect to server <my ip address>:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to <my ip address>:27017 :: caused by :: Connection refused :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:372:17
@(connect):2:6
exception: connect failed
exiting with code 1
```

I have followed many suggestions by others (for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60580265/connection-refused-connecting-to-remote-mongodb-server)) but none of them works. The bindIp is set to be `0.0.0.0` in /etc/mongo.conf. I checked the connection using telnet:

```
nc -vz <my ip address> 27017
```

and it gives:

```
nc: connectx to <my ip address> port 27017 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
```

However, checking on my desktop machine reveals that the firewall on port 27017 is open:

```
(base) exen@jingyang:~$ sudo ufw status verbose
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), disabled (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
27017                      ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
22                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere                         
27017 (v6)                 ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
22 (v6)                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

I'm wondering what could be the cause of this issue?

Comment: Your router might be blocking comm between peers.

Comment: @Martheen I added port 27017 to my WiFi port forwarding and it works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question: it turned out that it is simply the setting of my WiFi. It didn't have port 27017 open for communication. Once opened, the problem is resolved.